# How can I delete an old record and insert a new record with a pl/pgsql function?

Tags: postgresql

```
I have this table:
idsession  name    num_objects
1          James        1
2          Laure        2    
3          Daniel       3
```

I want to update the table with a new record

```
2          Laure        4
```

How can I delete a old record and update a new record with a pl/pgsql function with parameter idsession?

Example:
If idsession is in the table then delete old record and update the new.
If idsession is not in the table only update the new record.

Comment: It's unclear what you want, but maybe it is `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.

Comment: It seems to me you will need to create a `TRIGGER` on your table... Have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html